# geom_text labels swap places when values are the same

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text, direct-labels

I'm trying to use geom_text as the legend for my line graph, but I also need to have COUNT as labels (work requirement).

When I run the code below, I can get both labels, the values and the category names and format them differently so the legend is more obvious.

But if the final COUNT are the same, the order of the labels changes each time the code is run. So some times the correct COUNT lines up with the correct label for the legend, but run it again and the labels will have mixed up.

```
df <- data.frame(YEAR = c(2017,2018,2019,2017,2018,2019,2017,2018,2019),
            SPLIT = c("Cat A","Cat A","Cat A","Cat B","Cat B","Cat B","Cat C","Cat C","Cat C"),
            COUNT = c(11,12,15,6,8,12,15,14,12)
                 )
ggplot(df, aes(YEAR, COUNT, label = COUNT, colour = SPLIT, group = SPLIT)) +
geom_line(size = 1) +
scale_x_continuous(labels = as.character(df$YEAR), breaks =df$YEAR, limits = c(min(df$YEAR), max(df$YEAR+0.3)))+
geom_text_repel(data = subset(df, YEAR == max(YEAR)), aes(label = SPLIT), show.legend = FALSE, size = 4, fontface = "bold", hjust = "left",nudge_x = 0.2,direction = "y", segment.color = NA) +
  geom_text_repel(data = subset(df, YEAR == max(YEAR)), aes(label = COUNT), show.legend = FALSE, size = 3,direction = "y", segment.color = NA) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

I know that I can create an additional field using paste(Col1,Col2) and just use one geom_text, but then the labels are formatted the same and I wanted them to be different.

I've tried directlabels, but the labels were too close together. I reduced the font size but it was still too close together.

I suppose there are a few questions here:

1. Can I tweak my code to fix the order of the labels?
   or
2. Can I have different formatting for two parts of the same field?
   or.
3. How do I increase the spacing of labels, using directlabels?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hey - Please consider marking the solution as accepted by clicking the checkmark. Dong this will help others in the future who may have a similar problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about removing one of the `geom_text_repels` and passing in `SPLIT2` variable which utilizes the `glue` package to concatenate `SPLIT` and `COUNT`.

Doing this changes the ordering of the labels for `Cat C` and `Cat B`.

I would also suggest you consider changing the `nudge_x` from `0.2` to `0.05`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(ggrepel)
library(glue)

df <- data.frame(YEAR = c(2017,2018,2019,2017,2018,2019,2017,2018,2019),
            SPLIT = c("Cat A","Cat A","Cat A","Cat B","Cat B","Cat B","Cat C","Cat C","Cat C"),
            COUNT = c(11,12,15,6,8,12,15,14,12)
                 )


df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    SPLIT2 = glue("{SPLIT} - {COUNT}")
  )

ggplot(df, aes(YEAR, COUNT, label = COUNT, colour = SPLIT, group = SPLIT)) +
geom_line(size = 1) +
scale_x_continuous(labels = as.character(df$YEAR), 
                   breaks =df$YEAR, 
                   limits = c(min(df$YEAR), 
                              max(df$YEAR+0.3)))+
  geom_text_repel(data = subset(df, YEAR == max(YEAR)),
                  aes(label = SPLIT2),
                  show.legend = FALSE,
                  size = 4,
                  fontface = "bold",
                  hjust = "left",
                  nudge_x = 0.2,
                  direction = "y",
                  segment.color = NA) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]